# Cómo poner el foco en una fila de un GridView

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

¿Existe alguna propiedad del GridView para que cuando entre el evento onRowCommand, el mismo Grid sepa que fila (o registro) mandó el postback y regrese el foco a él? Me explico:

Tengo un grid hecho en asp.net con C# que me muestra varios registros (resultantes de una consulta a la base de datos). Tengo además (en ese Grid) el evento OnRowCommand y OnRowDataBound y me estoy enfrentando a que, cuando entra el evento RowCommand, en automático se hace un postback y el Grid se vuelve a cargar, entra el evento RowDataBound hace ciertas validaciones por registro y listo, el Grid se muestra de manera correcta.

Esto no tendría mayor complicación si se tratase de un GridView con 5 o 6 registros, pero cuando el Grid tiene 50 registros (o más) cada vez que se presiona un botón de algun registro y entra el RowCommand, en automático al cargarse el Grid de nuevo regresa al principio (al top del Grid) y el usuario tiene que volver a bajar (con el scroll) y buscar el registro en el que se quedó y continuar con su actividad...

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes mostrar un poco más de código y alguna captura para poder ayudarte. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822